# Debian 7.9 : How to split file with 7z into another folder located inside another mounted drive?

Tags: linux, debian, 7-zip

With Debian 7.9 and a cheap server (C1 by scaleway), how to split a big file with 7z into another folder located inside another mounted drive ?

My example: 
Split every 2GB using no compression a 124GB file.
The file is:

> /mnt/data/Takeout/Gmail/All mail Including Spam and Trash.mbox

The first mounted drive (called **mnt/data**) has only 14GB left out of 138GB.
The second mounted drive (called **mnt/data2**) has 138GB left out of 138GB.
So I first go into the folder :

```
cd /mnt/data/Takeout/Gmail/
```

Then I use this command line:

```
7z -v2g -mx0 a "All mail Including Spam and Trash".mbox.7z -wmnt/data2
```

but alas it split the big file into the same mounting drive (not into the second one).

Comment: If you just want to split the file without using compression, why don't you use the `split` command instead of `7z`?

Comment: Thanks for the info I will look into it. I selected 7zip because at a later stage I may use Windows to join back the files.

Comment: Here my successful first test : `cd /mnt/data/Takeout/Gmail/`    Then    `split -b2G "/mnt/data/Takeout/Gmail/All mail Including Spam and Trash.mbox" /mnt/data2/mail.dat` Thanks again ;)

Comment: this may also help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526930/cat-command-for-windows